# Python struct.error: integer out of range for 'q' format code

Tags: python, struct, casting, double

I'm having a problem, I want to cast a binary number into a double precission number.

After some searchs, I found some way, but I'm still having a problem, I can cast "little" numbers but not the big ones (double precission), here's my example code:

```
print unpack( "d", pack( "q", 4631069437225598976 ) )[ 0 ]
print unpack( "d", pack( "q", 13829563286724542464 ) )[ 0 ]
```

The first one has no problem, but the next one crashes with the error on the description.

The first number should be: 41.7274732
And the second one should be: -0.8899581

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I have already found one solution (not sure if it is the best one):


print unpack( ">d", binascii.unhexlify( "BFEC7A8980000000" ) )[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Q` for unsigned long long, instead of `q` for long long, will give the output you want:

```
from struct import pack, unpack

print unpack( "d", pack( "Q", 4631069437225598976 ) )[ 0 ]
print unpack( "d", pack( "Q", 13829563286724542464 ) )[ 0 ]
```

outputs:

```
41.7274742126
-0.889958143234
```

Edit:

please check carefully with your other big numbers because it might give the same error, we are just adding one bit in the most signicant bit position.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reviewing the range for the format applicable to the data you're using. I had a similar problem packing a positive 4 byte number as signed that was larger than 2147483647. Changing the format to unsigned allowed for inputs up to 4294967295 (packed as b'\xff\xff\xff\xff').

From [Python struct.pack() article on dqdongg.com](https://dqdongg.com/python/2019/05/03/Python-pack.html) and [this comment on pyinstaller's github](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4495) I found the references needed to change the expected format for the data I was packing. The error message in [this related question about format ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47776649/3282161) would've been more helpful to understand the problem I was having, instead of "struct.error: argument out of range".

[Format Type Quick Guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb5pB.png)