# python multiprocessing - OverflowError('cannot serialize a bytes object larger than 4GiB')

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, python-multiprocessing

We are running a script using the `multiprocessing` library (`python 3.6`), where a big `pd.DataFrame` is passed as an argument to a function :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time 

def my_function(big_df):
    # do something time consuming
    time.sleep(50)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(10) as p:
        res = {}
        output = {}
        for id, big_df in some_dict_of_big_dfs:
            res[id] = p.apply_async(my_function,(big_df ,))
        output = {id : res[id].get() for id in id_list}
```

The problem is that we are getting an error from the `pickle` library.

> Reason: 'OverflowError('cannot serialize a bytes objects larger than
> 4GiB',)'

We are aware than `pickle v4` can serialize larger objects [question related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704139/pickle-in-python3-doesnt-work-for-large-data-saving), [link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3154/), but we don't know how to modify the protocol that `multiprocessing` is using.

does anybody know what to do?
Thanks !!

Comment: @jasdhfiu-asef-aesf-asef-a-sgaa the version is python 3.6

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently is there an open [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue17560) about this topic , and there is a few related initiatives described on this particular [answer](https://bugs.python.org/issue17560#msg289548). I Found a way to change the default `pickle` protocol that is used in the `multiprocessing` library based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119053/how-to-change-the-serialization-method-used-by-pythons-multiprocessing). As was pointed out in the comments this solution **Only works with Linux and OS multiprocessing lib**

Solution:

You first create a new separated module

> pickle4reducer.py

```
from multiprocessing.reduction import ForkingPickler, AbstractReducer

class ForkingPickler4(ForkingPickler):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        if len(args) > 1:
            args[1] = 2
        else:
            args.append(2)
        super().__init__(*args)

    @classmethod
    def dumps(cls, obj, protocol=4):
        return ForkingPickler.dumps(obj, protocol)


def dump(obj, file, protocol=4):
    ForkingPickler4(file, protocol).dump(obj)


class Pickle4Reducer(AbstractReducer):
    ForkingPickler = ForkingPickler4
    register = ForkingPickler4.register
    dump = dump
```

And then, in your main script you need to add the following:

```
import pickle4reducer
import multiprocessing as mp
ctx = mp.get_context()
ctx.reducer = pickle4reducer.Pickle4Reducer()

with mp.Pool(4) as p:
    # do something
```

That will probably solve the problem of the overflow.

**But, warning, you might consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47776649/5318634) before doing anything** or you might reach the same error as me:

> 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647

(the reason of this error is well explained in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47776649/5318634) above). Long story short, `multiprocessing` send data through all its process using the `pickle` protocol, if you are already reaching the `4gb` limit, that probably means that you might consider redefining your functions more as "void" methods rather than input/output methods. All this inbound/outbound data increase the RAM usage, is probably inefficient by construction (my case) and it might be better to point all process to the same object rather than create a new copy for each call.

hope this helps.

Comment: I got the following error:
`src\pickle4reducer.py", line 6, in __init__
    args[1] = 2
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`

Any suggestions?

Comment: @BarbarianSpock in what OS are you working on? (we tried same code in mac and worked fine) I think that the implementation of the `multiprocessing` library is different on windows. That might be the reason.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the problem..i've tried the code in two environments. In one of them everything works fine (linux) (that's why i posted that code), and another (windows) and I got the same error as you... (probably because the *args var changes). Apparently both env should be similar (created with almost the same conda req list) but I still can't understand why works in one env and not in another.

Comment: We were using a windows enviroment, however after your explanation we tested it in a linux enviroment using python 3.6 (the default SO python was 3.5, but the `multiprocessing` seems different). We managed it to work.

Comment: Depending on the start method, this patch will fail or not. With `get_context() or get_context('fork')` everything works great, but with `get_context('spwan')` or `get_context('forkserver')` it does not work.

Comment: @pablo in line `ns.df = big_df` ,I am getting error :
`mgr = ctx.Manager()`
`ns = mgr.Namespace()`
`ns.df = big_df`
Error:
`cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
OverflowError: cannot serialize a bytes object larger than 4 GiB`

Comment: As @hongkail says in the next answer, I've solved both problems by updating to python from python 3.7 to python 3.8

Answer (score 1):

Supplementing answer from Pablo

The following problem can be resolved be Python3.8, if you are okay to use this version of python:

```
'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```