# Read a lot of data using pool.map ('error("'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647")')

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pickle, pathos

I'm reading data from databases. I need to read from several servers (nodes) simultaniuosly, so I want to use pool.map.

I'm trying to do this way:

```
import pathos.pools as pp
import pandas as pd
import urllib

class DataProvider():
    def __init__(self, hosts):

        self.hosts_read = hosts

    def read_data(self, host_index):
        '''
        Read data from current node

        '''
        limit = 1000000
        host = self.hosts_read[host_index]
        query = f"select FIELD1 from table_name limit {limit}"
        url = urllib.parse.urlencode({'query': query})
        df = pd.io.parsers.read_csv(f'http://{host}:8123/?{url}',
                                    sep="\t", names=['FIELD1'], low_memory=False)
        return df


    def pool_read(self, num_workers):
        '''
        Read from data using Pool of workers.
        Return list of lists - every list is a data from current worker.
        '''
        pool = pp.ProcessPool(num_workers)
        result = pool.map(self.read_data, range(len(self.hosts_read)))
        return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    provider = DataProvider(host=['server01.com', 'server02.com'])
    data = provider.pool_read(num_workers=n_cpu)
```

It works perfect while limit is not so much (below 4 millions). And crushes if it is bigger:

> multiprocess.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result:
>   '[my_pandas_dataframe]'. Reason: 'error("'i' format requires
>   -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647")'

I found some answers about it: it is because we cannot return from the pool peace of data bigger than 2 GB. For example: [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776486/python-struct-error-i-format-requires-2147483648-number-2147483647). But there is no any ideas or solutions, how to work if I need load bigger parts!

P.S. I use [pathos](https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos) module but it is not important here - the same error for multiprocessing module too.