# Pandas multiprocessing on very large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use the multiprocessing package to compute a function on a very large Pandas dataframe. However I ran into a problem with the following error:

```
OverflowError: cannot serialize a bytes objects larger than 4GiB
```

After applying the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562221/python-multiprocessing-overflowerrorcannot-serialize-a-bytes-object-larger-t) and using protocol 4 for pickling, I ran into the following error instead, which is also quoted by the solution itself:

```
error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776486/python-struct-error-i-format-requires-2147483648-number-2147483647/47776649#47776649) then suggests to use the dataframe as a global variable. 
But ideally I would like the dataframe to still be an input of the function, without having the multiprocessing library copying and pickling it multiple times in the background.

Is there some other way I can design the code to not run into the issue?

I was able to replicate the problem with this example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import functools

print('Total memory usage for the dataframe: {} GB'.format(df.memory_usage().sum() / 1e9))

def slow_function(some_parameter, df):
  time.sleep(1)
  return some_parameter

parameters = list(range(100))

with mp.Pool(20) as pool:
  function = functools.partial(slow_function, df=df)

  results = pool.map(function, parameters)
```

Comment: I think slicing the dataframe could be a good option if you dont have any problem with that

Comment: Good suggestion. I thought about it, however unfortunately the function needs to do an operation on the whole dataframe altogether.

Answer (score 1):

try Dask

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

docs : https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html